# No identify button after launching application in application modeller - BluePrism

Tags: launch, identify, blueprism

I am using BluePrism v5.0.12 and I am trying to identify elements from a launched application in Application Modeller. (I used the Windows application type in the modeler configuration)
From some tutorials I saw, the launch button changes to Identify button after the app is launched, however, my Launch button just becomes disabled. Additionally, I have a diagnostics button that takes a snapshot of all elements.

The snapshot result is below (it is really long so I am just going to paste the beginning - note: the app is a simple sign in window):

```
WINDOW:+WindowText=<UNKNOWN> +ClassName= CtrlID=0 X=0 Y=0 Width=1 Height=1 +Visible=False +ScreenVisible=False +Enabled=True Active=False Ordinal=0 ChildCount=6 AncestorsText= AncestorCount=0 TypeName= ScreenBounds=RECT:0,0,0,0
```

WINDOW:+WindowText="Sign in" +ClassName=WindowsForms10.Window CtrlID=0 X=807 Y=-886 Width=262 Height=180 +Visible=True +ScreenVisible=True +Enabled=True Active=False Ordinal=1 ChildCount=5 AncestorsText=" " AncestorCount=1 TypeName= ScreenBounds=RECT:811,-854,-712,1064

Has this happened to anyone else? Where can I find the identify button?

Here is a snapshot of my application modeller window:
[Application modeller window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha9sm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see "identify" button, you need to launch your application, and choose "element 1" from the left side panel.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @AntsaR I am facing the same issue now.. I have launched application via Application modeller launch but still not getting "identify" button in "element 1".

I am try to create VBO for Calculator, I am using Windows 10, Blue Prism V5.0.11.0

Comment: As Andrzej said, after you launch your application through Application modeler, you have to select element1 from the left panel and only then will you be able to see the identify button.  Can you take a screenshot?